# GUI Development - Language and Builder

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, erlang, c++builder

I have a nice piece of software written in Erlang, over the past few weeks I have developed a gui using wxWidgets.  Its decent at best, the nightmares come from the fact that there is no gui wysiwyg type of a program that writes erlang.

So..

I am looking to code my gui in another language and link it somehow (the somehow is not important, I will figure it out)

I have looked into both QT and C++ Builder and am strongly considering either of the two.  However before I finally take the plunge I need some advice from users who have been here.  Which of the two should I choose and is there a better option?

wxWidgets and GTK are out of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've covered the range of modern C++ GUI options (two you're considering, and two you're not). Qt is an excellent choice, but I've never used C++ Builder.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't any experience with C++ Builder, but considering QT I can say, that it's very good choice. Plenty of good straightforward examples and the best reference documentation I have ever seen make learning QT quite easy process.

Besides that I have found a small [article](http://www.richelbilderbeek.nl/CppCompareCppBuilderAndQtCreator.htm) concerning comparison of Qt and C++ Builder.

Comment: note that the linked article is quite old.  There have been about 5 versions of Builder C++ since version 6.0